# How to prove there is no bijection between two different natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to draw a contradiction from "there exists a bijection between natural numbers $\boldsymbol{3}$ and $\boldsymbol{4}$" using the pigeon-hole theorem. This theorem is given by

> For any $\boldsymbol{n} \in \mathbb{N}$, if a map $f: \boldsymbol{n} \to \boldsymbol{n}$ is one-one, then it is onto.

Here is my argument. As
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{3} = \left\{\boldsymbol{0},\boldsymbol{1},\boldsymbol{2}\right\},
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{4} = \left\{\boldsymbol{0},\boldsymbol{1},\boldsymbol{2},\boldsymbol{3}\right\},
\end{equation*}
and there exists a bijection between $\boldsymbol{3}$ and $\boldsymbol{4}$, then there has to be a bijection $f: \boldsymbol{4} \to \boldsymbol{3}$, which is one-one and onto. As
\begin{equation*}
\boldsymbol{3} \subsetneq \boldsymbol{4},
\end{equation*}
then there exists a map $g: \boldsymbol{3} \to \boldsymbol{3}$, which is one-one but not onto. The existence of $g$ contradicts the pigeon hold theorem. Thus, there cannot be a bijection between $\boldsymbol{3}$ and $\boldsymbol{4}$.

I am wondering how to prove a more general proposition as follows (although it seems quite obvious):

> For any $\boldsymbol{m},\boldsymbol{n}\in \mathbb{N}$, if $\boldsymbol{m} \neq \boldsymbol{n}$, then there does not exist a bijection between $\boldsymbol{m}$ and $\boldsymbol{n}$.

In my understanding, this proposition has to be proved using mathematical induction. We should conduct mathematical induction on one variable while keep the other one fixed.

Comment: For me it seems that your argument is correct. Moreover, I think it may be easier to prove the generalization you proposed by contradiction using the pigeonhole principle and the thricotomy of natural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes so by induction works fine. Consider $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, $n\neq m$. Without loss of generality, assume that $n > m$. We can apply induction on $M:= max\{m,n\}$. We can prove the result for $M = 2$ by exhausting all of the possible maps easily. Assume the result holds for $M = N \geq 3$. Now suppose $M = N + 1$ and take a map $f:\textbf{m}\to \textbf{n}$ (with $n > m$; so $n = N+ 1$ here). Assume this map is bijective. Then the restriction will be a map on $\textbf{m - 1}$ which will be bijective onto $\textbf{n - 1}$ (just by inspecting where the element we "remove" from $\textbf{m}$ gets sent to; relabel $\textbf{n}$ if necessary), contradicting the induction hypothesis.